# Strange compiler difference between Eclipse and javac

Tags: java, javac

The following snippet (abstracted from real-world code) compiles and runs in Eclipse.

package1/Outer.java:

```
package package1;

import package1.Outer.Mid.Inner;
import package2.Bar;

public class Outer {
    final Mid mid = new Mid();

    public Outer() {
        mid.setInner(new Inner() {
            @Override public void foo() {
                System.out.println("In Outer.foo()");
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Mid implements Bar {
        private Inner inner;

        public void setInner(Inner inner) {
            this.inner = inner;
        }

        public Inner getInner() {
            return this.inner;
        }

        @Override
        public void bar() {}

        interface Inner {
            void foo();
        }
    }

}
```

package2/Bar.java:

```
package package2;

public interface Bar {
    void bar();
}
```

However, it fails with this error when compiling using javac:

```
package1\Outer.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Bar
location: class package1.Outer
        public static class Mid implements Bar {
                                           ^
package1\Outer.java:42: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
                @Override
                ^
2 errors
```

Now, if I switch the order of the import statements, like so:

```
import package2.Bar;
import package1.Outer.Mid.Inner;
```

...then it compiles in both Eclipse and javac.  Clearly the order of the import statements seems to matter...but why?

Notes:

- I tested this using Java JDK 1.6.0_30, and also Java JDK 1.7.0_21.  If this is a bug that has since been fixed, that would be good to know.
- It seems strange to me that the `package1.Outer.Mid.Inner` import is even necessary, given the `Inner` interface is nested within Outer.java, but both Eclipse and javac seem to require it
- I discovered this problem trying to run an Ant build of production code that had a similar structure.  Everything was building fine in Eclipse, but the Ant script just refused to go through.

Comment: I don't know for sure but it's likely Eclipse is giving a different compile command than you are by hand.  Perhaps the order is inverted.  The only other possibility is different versions of the java compiler.

Comment: Any chance you could delete the superfluous parts of your code and leave us with the minimum that still produces the same strange results?

Comment: @Gene Eclipse has its own compiler.

Comment: @arshaji I cut out most of the bloat, is that better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug, as reported on Oracle's bug database [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7101822).

According to the [JLS §7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5), the order of `import`-statements should not matter.

Comment: @arshaji the updated link certainly looks to match my case, good find.  For the JLS, I don't see any explicit mention that import statement order doesn't matter...is it an implicit understanding or am I just blind?

Comment: @KevinK The fact that the JLS doesn't explicitly state that the order matters implies that it doesn't.